# Refresh part of webpage using document.URL in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

What specifically do you plug in the document.URL part of this?

```
 $('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');
```

None of these following seem to work:

```
  $('#example').load(document.URL +  ' #example');
  $('#example').load(index.php +  ' #example');
  $('#example').load(https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/ +  ' #example');
   $('#example').load('https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/' +  ' #example');
```

This is the simple way of doing a refresh of the table using datatables but it did not work either.

```
 table.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: What's the URL you want to load?  The fourth example looks fine, aside from an unnecessary concatenation of two string literals.  When you try that, how does it fail?

Comment: https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/   That link I am trying to load...yep i will change my project code to see if any errors come up? the second to last line does not have the string literals in it.

Comment: i think I found another problem... this part https://     is commenting out the rest of the link...! Why the color looks green afterwards.

Comment: Well, yes, a syntax error will certainly produce syntax errors.  Use quotes for string literals, exactly like you already do in your string literals.

Comment: datatables-ajax.000webhostapp.com      link should work if i just delete the http// part

Comment: barmar says i need a seperate div-container for second part... will look into this too

Comment: He's correct, but before that you're going to need to have an actual valid URL string to pass to the `.load()` function.  Just put the actual URL into a string literal.  Don't take out the `//`, don't add another `https:` for whatever reason... Simply use a string with the URL you want to fetch.

Comment: Cool So for future readers: `$('#example-container').load("https//:databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/" +  ' #example'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.load()` loads the selected part of the returned document *inside* the element you're running it on, it doesn't replace the element. So the code you've written will try to create:

```
<div id="example">
    <div id="example">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to put a container around the element. So the original HTML should be something like:

```
<div id="example-container">
    <div id="example">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you can do:

```
$("#example-container").load(location.URL + " #example")
```

Comment: Wondering if OP should empty the contents of the container before loading the new content. `$("#example-container").html("").load(location.URL + " #example")`

Comment: No, it's not necessary, `.load()` will do that itself. Your version will empty the container even if `.load()` fails.

Comment: cant put #example in a div got a datatables error. I did this instead: ` <div id="example-container"> <table id="example"   ` Should that still work? because that with ` $('#example-container').load("https//:databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/" + ' #example'); ` did not seem to fully work.

Comment: Error message when i tried putting #example in a div     "DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (DIV). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2"

Comment: DIV was just an assumption, it can be any element type. All that's important is that you wrap it in something else, and use that container in the `.load()` call.

Comment: Ok well you helped a lot so I’ll mark as answer. Think I may have a small DataTables error somewhere I’ll hav to rebuild a simple example and go from there